# expr match problem in shell

Tags: regex, shell, match

In an sh shell script I wrote the following:

```
opr=+  
echo `expr match "$opr" '[+\-x/]'`
```

but I get this error when ran:

```
expr: syntax error
```

What am I doing wrong? I get the same error when I make opr equal to - and / .

Another interesting thing I found is when I wrote this:

```
opr=a  
echo `expr match "$opr" '[+\-x/]'`
```

it returns this:

```
1
```

This means that it matched the string "a" to one of +, -, x, and /. But that makes no sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First case: `+`

`+` has a special meaning to expr:

```
   + TOKEN
          interpret TOKEN as a string, even if it is a
          keyword like `match' or an operator like `/'
```

Second case: `a`

your regexp is a range operation, matching characters from `+` to `x`, which includes most alnums.  To make the `-` be matched literally in a charclass, it must be the first or last character; backslashing it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks, upon further searching, the way to interpret a keyword as a string is to use the 'quote' argument, which is a GNU extension and won't work if the 'POSIXLY_CORRECT' environment variable is set.
[reference is here](http://ss64.com/bash/expr.html)